# Display an array of NSViewControllers horizontal in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

what is the best way to display a bunch of NSViewControllers horizontal side by side inside a horizontal scrollable view?

Each "row" must be resizable by its own like a split view.

I tests a few ideas with split view and scroll view but can't get a good starting point.

Thanks for a kick. 
ps.

**UPDATE** 
here is what i've got:

I add a scrollview to my main view (ColoumnMasterViewController) border to border. I add a second ViewController to the storyboard and named them "coloumn_view_controller"

[image]

In the ColoumnMasterViewController i add the coloumn_view_controller.view a couple of times:

```
class ColoumnMasterViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    for i in 1...10 {
        let vc: NSViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("coloumn_view_controller") as! NSViewController

        vc.view.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: (130 * i), y: (i * 10)))
        println("set to \(vc.view.bounds)")

        scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
    }
    scrollView.needsLayout = true
}
}
```

But scrolling is not available.

[image]

So, how can i create a view inside a scrollview that is bigger than the current viewport? I suppose if i solve this, I'm able to fix my other splitview problems.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE 2**
Finally i get it so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollingView: NSScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    var contentView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: self.view.frame.height))

    contentView.wantsLayer = true
    contentView.layer?.backgroundColor =  NSColor.redColor().CGColor

    for i in 0...10 {
        let vc: NSViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("coloumn_view_controller") as! NSViewController
        vc.view.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: (i * 130), y: 0))

        vc.view.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 130, height: self.view.frame.height))
        contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
    }

    scrollingView.documentView = contentView

    autoLayout(contentView)
}
```

[image]

but my autoLayout() didn't work so well. How would you implement autoLayout that the contentView will pin on top, bottom, trailing and leading of the superview?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a "Super View Controller"
2. Make the "Super View Controller" display the view property of each sub `UIViewController`

The "Super View Controller" should probably be a `UITableViewViewController` instance to help you scrolling and resizing rows

Question is quite broad, so it's unclear how much guidance do you need, don't hesitate to comment to request clarifications.

Comment: Hi Antzi, thanks a lot. My problem is the  "display the view property" part. I will play around with the NSListViewController. I build up a project and will come back. ;-)

Comment: What is an NSListViewController?

Comment: My bad. I meant UITableViewController

Comment: The idea is to set the view of your sub view controllers as the view for each cell of the super view controller.

Comment: i updated my question and posted a example. Can you help me with the scrollview?

Comment: @PeterShaw It seems you didn't set the contentSize of your scrollview ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a split view controller. You can have as many dividers as you want.

In recent versions of OSX view controllers can host the content of other view controllers.

Comment: But how to add a split view into a scroll view? Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution and stick it together into a demo projekt: https://github.com/petershaw/DynamicScrollViewExample

The Trick is to add a NSView and set it into the documentView, than manage the documentView correctly with autolayout:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    contentView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: self.view.frame.height))

    scrollingView.documentView = contentView

    autoLayout(contentView!)
}
```

Autolayout:

```
func autoLayout(contentView: NSView){
    let topPinContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    let bottomPinContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
          item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )

    println("heightContraints \(contentView.superview!.frame.height)")
    let heightContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview!
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    println("widthtContraints \(contentView.superview!.frame.width)")
    let calculatedWith: CGFloat = (CGFloat) (contentView.subviews.count * 130)
    widthtContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: nil
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    widthtContraints!.constant = calculatedWith

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
          topPinContraints
         , bottomPinContraints
         , heightContraints
         , widthtContraints!
    ])

    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.needsLayout = true

}
```

and than do a layout update after resizing the content:

```
func updateWidth(){
    let calculatedWith: CGFloat = (CGFloat) (contentView!.subviews.count * 130)
    if (widthtContraints != nil) {
        widthtContraints!.constant = calculatedWith
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is a good solution? Comments are welcome. Now, I can replace the view with an NSSplitView subclass.